# How do I read a JSON feed to populate a single dimensional array?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am trying to read in the values contained in a JSON feed into a one dimensional array - with array elements storing values for ShowProgress, Orange, Blue and Target into an array of class Progress. Then I want to use these to update a progress bar (see third code section). I can't extract these values (perhaps they're not being set?):

Here's what the feed looks like (it passes JSONlint):

```
{
"ShowProgress": {
"ShowProgress": "TRUE",
"Orange": "0",
"Blue": "0",
"Target": "18"
 }
 }
```

This routine is where I can't seem to read in the array values correctly, rem statements indicate where I have suspicions:

```
public class FetchProgress extends AsyncTask<OpportunityActivity, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
private OpportunityActivity opportunityActivity;

@Override
protected ArrayList doInBackground(OpportunityActivity... activity) {

    // This may be incorrect - I don't want a two dimensional
    // just a one dimensional array
opportunityActivity = activity[0];

    ArrayList<Progress> progresses = new ArrayList<Progress>();
    String readFeed = readFeed();

    try {           
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readFeed);            
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.optString("ShowProgress"));              
Progress progress = new Progress();                    
progress.setTarget(jsonArray.optInt("Target"));            
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This routine reads the JSON:

```
 public String readFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();      

    SharedPreferences settings =     
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(opportunityActivity);        
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.webfeedurl.com/stuff.php");
    try 
 {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;

        int a=0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        a++;
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Finally back in OpportunityActivity I want to be using the values in the array to set my ProgressBar:

```
public void updateProgress(ArrayList<Progress> progress) {
    ProgressBar progressHours  = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressHours);      
    // How do I get the array list variables out to set my progress bar....
    // The next line is wrong 
    progressHours.setProgress(progress.getTarget());
}
```

And here's the class file: (There are more variables I'm trying to read than just target, hence I'm using an array).

```
public class Progress {

private int target;

public int getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(int target) {
    this.target = target;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: So I found an issue - I was using JSONArray when I should have been using JSONObject in doInBackground. I'm still stuck as I can't seem to extract my values. I've tried 
`Log.e(OpportunityActivity.class.toString(), "Target:" + progress.getTarget());`
but this doesn't show it's captured anything (or the value of target is blank).

Comment: My problem is that back in updateProgress this doesn't pick up the value from the JSON:  
`progressHours.setProgress(progress.getTarget());`  
It looks like the JSON isn't getting read into the variable, the variable remains 0, not 18 - the value getting read in.

Comment: I've now corrected it so that the parser focuses on the right section of the JSON - ShowProgress. However I still can't seem to extract Target using `progress.setTarget(jsonArray.optInt("Target"));`